Tetrahedron analogue of a triangle Cevians property
It's a cute Olympaid geometry problem to prove that given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with three Cevians $AA_1,BB_1, CC_1$ intersecting at an interior point $M$:
$$ab+bc+ca+2abc = 1 \quad (1)$$
where
$$\dfrac{MA_1}{AM} = a, \dfrac{MB_1}{BM} = b, \dfrac{MC_1}{CM} = c.$$
My question is - what is the Tetrahedron analogue of this if there is any ?
The proof for the triangle case is just many Ceva or Menelaus applications. In particular, one can start with the identity:
$$\dfrac{AM}{MA_1} = \dfrac{AB_1}{B_1C} + \dfrac{AC_1}{C_1B}$$
and soon obtain $(1)$.

First, a proof for equation $(1)$ will be given. Then, an analogous method will be employed for the case of a tetrahedron.
Part 1: Proof for $(1)$
For a triangle $\triangle XYZ$, let $[XYZ]$ denote its area.
We have $\dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} = \dfrac{[MBC]}{[ABC]}$. This is because the ratio of these areas is equal to the ratio of the altitudes from points $M$ and $A$ to side $BC$ (due to base $[BC]$ being common), and the ratio of these altitudes is equal to $\dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|}$ by similar triangles.
Similarly, we have $\dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} = \dfrac{[MAC]}{[ABC]}$ and $\dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} = \dfrac{[MAB]}{[ABC]}$.
Due to $[ABC] = [MBC] + [MAC] + [MAB]$, the three equalities above give us $$\dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} + \dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} + \dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} = 1.$$
From $\dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AM|}=a$, the ratio $\dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|}$ can be computed as
$\begin{align}
\dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} &= \dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AM|+|MA_1|} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{ \frac{|AM|+|MA_1|}{|MA_1|} } \\
&= \dfrac{1}{ 1 + \frac{|AM|}{|MA_1|}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1+\frac 1 a} \\
&= \dfrac a {a+1}.
\end{align}$
Similarly, we obtain $\dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} = \dfrac b {b+1}$ and $\dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} = \dfrac c {c+1}$
We have already obtained
$\begin{align}
1 &= \dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} + \dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} + \dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} \\
&= \dfrac a {a+1} + \dfrac b {b+1} + \dfrac c {c+1}  \\
&= \dfrac{a(b+1)(c+1) + b(a+1)(c+1) + c(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)} \\
&= \dfrac{ 3abc + 2(ab+ac+bc) + (a+b+c) }{ abc + (ab+ac+bc) + (a+b+c) + 1 }
\end{align}$
which implies $\boxed{ab+ac+bc + 2abc = 1}$, as desired.
Part 2: The case for tetrahedron
Let $ABCD$ be a tetrahedron in the space and point $M$ in the interior of it. Let $AM$ intersect the plane $BCD$ at $A'$, and analogously for $B',C',D'$. Denote
$$\dfrac{MA_1}{AM} = a, \dfrac{MB_1}{BM} = b, \dfrac{MC_1}{CM} = c, \dfrac{MD_1}{DM} = d.$$
Also, for a tetrahedron $WXYZ$, let $[WXYZ]$ denote its volume.
Analogous reasoning to the case of the triangle gives us, by $[ABCD] = [MBCD] + [MACD] + [MABD] + [MABC]$,
$$ \dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} + \dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} + \dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} + \dfrac{|MD_1|}{|DD_1|} = 1 $$
where
$$ \dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} = \dfrac a {a+1} , \dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} = \dfrac b {b+1} , \dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} = \dfrac c {c+1} , \dfrac{|MD_1|}{|DD_1|} = \dfrac d {d+1} . $$
Therefore,
$\begin{align}
1 &= \dfrac{|MA_1|}{|AA_1|} + \dfrac{|MB_1|}{|BB_1|} + \dfrac{|MC_1|}{|CC_1|} + \dfrac{|MD_1|}{|DD_1|} \\
&= \dfrac a {a+1} + \dfrac b {b+1} + \dfrac c {c+1} + \dfrac d {d+1} \\
&= \dfrac{a(b+1)(c+1)(d+1) + b(a+1)(c+1)(d+1) + c(a+1)(b+1)(d+1) + d(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)} \\
&= \dfrac{ 4abcd + 3(abc + abd + acd + bcd) + 2(ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd) + (a + b + c + d) }{ abcd + (abc + abd + acd + bcd) + (ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd) + (a + b + c + d) + 1 }
\end{align}$
which gives us the desired equality as $$ \boxed{ (ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd) + 2(abc + abd + acd + bcd) + 3abcd = 1 } . $$
